# Loading collection on User at login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Ok, so I have customized ApplicationUser, I need to load up a collection when the user logs in, and I'm just trying to find the best way to do that.  I've looked at the examples on the web, but those only customize the ApplicationUser by adding custom properties (not Collections).  I need to load up an IList<> when the user logs in.  I see a couple of ways to do this, and I'm wondering which would be considered the "best" way (I know this is somewhat subjective, but I think this is somewhat new ground).

Anyway, in the Login method on the AcccountController we have this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {

                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I could add a line after the `await SigninAsync()` to load my collection, but that seems wasteful, as the UserManager is already going to the database.  What I really want is some way to tell the user manager to `.Include()` my collection when it queries the database for the user.  What I'm looking at is inheriting from the `UserStore<ApplicationUser>` and overriding the `FindByNameAsync()` function that is called by the `UserManager`:

```
   public virtual Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();
        IQueryable<TUser> entitySet = 
            from u in this._userStore.EntitySet
            where u.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()
            select u;
        return Task.FromResult<TUser>(entitySet.FirstOrDefault<TUser>());
    }
```

and override it for the customized ApplicationUser that I'm using and load up my properties.  Is this the way this should be done, or am I overlooking something in `AspNet.Identity` somewhere that would handle this more simply?

---

So that blew up in my face quickly, it would seem you aren't going to inherit from `UserStore<TUser>` and get access to *anything* that you might actually want to use when overriding one of these methods, as it's all `internal` or `private`.  So short of copying and pasting all of `UserStore<TUser>` and reworking the one method I want are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
public class PatientPortalUserStore<TUser> : UserStore<TUser>
    where TUser : ApplicationUser
{

    public PatientPortalUserStore(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        this._userStore = new EntityStore<TUser>(context);
    }

    private EntityStore<TUser> _userStore;

    public override Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        //This is the important piece to loading your own collection on login
        IQueryable<TUser> entitySet =
            from u in this._userStore.EntitySet.Include(u=>u.MyCustomUserCollection)
            where u.UserName.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()
            select u;
        return Task.FromResult<TUser>(entitySet.FirstOrDefault<TUser>());
    }
}


//Had to define this because EntityStore used by UserStore<TUser> is internal
class EntityStore<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public DbContext Context
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DbSet<TEntity> DbEntitySet
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> EntitySet
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DbEntitySet;
        }
    }

    public EntityStore(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbEntitySet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.DbEntitySet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.Context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public virtual Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(object id)
    {
        return this.DbEntitySet.FindAsync(new object[] { id });
    }
}
```